# Android RoleManager remove role RoleManager.ROLE_SMS for own package

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sms, role-manager

I have sms backup app that backup and restore SMS only
so when i restore sms I need to set default Massage App. then after Restore i don't need to stay default Massage App.

So my question is how to remove my app default to Massage App.
and also for old version belove **Android Q**.

Code -

```
fun saveSms(values: ContentValues) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
            if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
                if (roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
                    contentResolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, values)
                } else {
                    val i = roleManager
                        .createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)

                    smsRunnable = Runnable {
                        saveSms(values)
                        smsRunnable = null
                    }
                    startActivityForResult(i, 5444)
                }
            }
            return
        }

        if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this) != packageName) {
            val intent = Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT)
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
            smsRunnable = Runnable {
                saveSms(values)
                smsRunnable = null
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 5444)
        } else {
            contentResolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, values)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With versions previous to Android Q, i use SharedPreferences.

```
String appDefault = getSharedPreferences("default", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("appDefault", "com.android.contacts");
    String paquete = getPackageName();
    String appCallerActual = getSystemService(TelecomManager.class).getDefaultDialerPackage();
    String cambio = appCallerActual.equals(paquete) ? appDefault : paquete;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager) getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER);
        Log.d(TAG, "isRoleAvailable: " + roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER));
        Log.d(TAG, "isRoleHeld: " + roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_DIALER));
        //HERE I CAN'T CHANGE TO OTHER APP, SORRY;
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_REQUEST);

    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER);
        intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME,
                cambio);
        startActivityForResult(intent,CODE_REQUEST);
    }
```

In case of Android Q i can't do it.